# Node.js with dynamical object, how to update it?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 
  res.json([
    {id:1, username:"Random guy"},
    {id:2, username:"Random guy2"},
  ])

  
});

module.exports = router;
```

Let's say I want to add/change some json object, how can I update without restarting server? Is nodemon the option to go, or how should i think?

Answer (score 1):

Nodemon is used to detect changes on your node app, and restart the server if it's already running. You can do the standard `$ node server.js` (example) to run your serve, and make changes to your app, the server will not restart.

However, the changes you've made **will not** take effect until you stop the server and restart. In a nutshell, changes made in code will only take effect when the server is restarted.